# Expectation of a constant (basic)

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Show that $E(c)=c,\forall c\in \mathbb{R}$.

I thought about two ways to show that.

1. $E(c)=\int_\Omega c\ dP=c\int_\Omega dP=c.P(\Omega)=c$;
2. Let $f=c$ a.e.. Then $f=c.\chi_1 (\{f=c\})+b.\chi_2(\{f\neq c\})$ as a simple function. Then $E(f)=\int_\Omega f dP=c .P(\{f=c\})$. Clearly, $P(\{f=c\})=1$, otherwise the sum of this probability with the probability of its complement wouldn't be 1.

Are both acceptable?

I tend to think that the second is more appropriated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second proof is not okay.

$f=c$ a.e. does not imply that $f$ is a simple function.

It might take distinct values on $\{f\neq c\}$ so it is not okay to write $f=c\chi_{\{f=c\}}+b\chi_{\{f\neq c\}}$ which suggests that $f$ always takes values in $\{c,b\}$.

Also your $b$ is somehow "falling from the sky".

Proof 1) works well as proof for $\mathbb E(c)=c$.

Secondly we have the general statement: $$f=g\text{ a.e.}\implies \int f=\int g\tag1$$whenever at least one of $f,g$ is integrable.

This together tells us that *also* $\mathbb Ef=c$ if $f=c$ a.e..

Comment: I agree with you. What if I put $b=0$?

Comment: That does not help because then again $f$ can only take two values: $c$ and $0$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I knew the converse result of (1) only.

Comment: The converse is not true. What we do have is: $\int|f-g|=0\implies f=g\text{ a.e.}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your correct observations.

Comment: You are very welcome.